# C# - listbox - экспорт файлов в посторонний софт

Tags: c#, .net

1. Есть ListBox который содержит список файлов прим. (D:\text01.txt)
2. Как реализовать экспорт этих файлов из ListBox к примеру в редактор notepad++ ?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под экспортом? Обычно это формирование выходного файла, который способна прочитать другая программа и в данном случае вы получите тот же `D:\text01.txt`, который надо будет открыть в notepad++. Программно его можно открыть через `Process.Start("notepad.exe", "D:\text01.txt");`. Но не все программы способны так открываться с аргументами, это зависит от самих программ.

Comment: Эспорт - я имею ввиду что все эти файлы, нужно открыть определенным софтом, за пример взял notepad++. К примеру можно добавить кнопку "Экспорт" по нажатию на которой, произойдет открытие всех файлов в notepad++ (или выделенных, но это уже детали)

Comment: Сам язык C# тут может только обратиться к операционной системе через [Process.Start( ... );](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-2.0), которая работает, как если бы вы набирали команды в командной строке. Если вы передадите ей название файла, то ОС попробует открыть его программой по умолчанию. Если вы передадите ей путь к программе, она откроет эту программу. Некоторые программы поддерживают аргументы, как в примере выше - если notepad++ передать путь к файлу, он его откроет. Но так работают не все программы.

Comment: Отлично, все работает.